# Triggering an Airflow DAG from terminal always keep running state

Tags: airflow

I am trying to use `airflow trigger_dag dag_id` to trigger my dag, but it just show me running state and doesn't do anymore.

I have searched for many questions, but all people just say dag id paused. the problem is my dag is unpaused, but also keep the running state.

Note: I can use one dag to trigger another one in Web UI. But it doesn't work in command line.
please see the snapshot as below

[image: Running DAG]

Comment: Is the scheduler running?

Comment: yes，scheduler is running

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue many times, The state of the task is not running, it is not queued either, it's stuck after we 'clear'. Sometimes I found the task is going to Shutdown state before getting into stuck. And after a large time the instance will be failed, still, the task status will be in white. I have solved it in many ways, I
 can't say its reason or exact solution, but try one of this:

- Try trigger dag command again with the same Execution date and time instead of the clear option.
- Try backfill it will run only unsuccessful instances.
- or try with a different time within the same interval it will create another instance which is fresh and not have the issue.